# How to find Internal linking of pages in Magento 1.9.3.6?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.0.1, ce-1.9.1.0, magento1.9.3

webmaster tools is showing more than 500 internal link on one of my website url. many links does not relate to this page. I want to know that link structure of my webpages, is  corrected or not.

is there any tool in magento to find out internal page link or broken links?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing these chrome plugins. For any site, you can use these tools.

1. To find broken links - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/broken-link-checker/nibppfobembgfmejpjaaeocbogeonhch?hl=en
2. To find all the links in the given page - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-grabber/caodelkhipncidmoebgbbeemedohcdma

Hope it helps you.